# how to center 2 images with vertical and horizontal

Tags: image, center, centering

**i need help...**

take a view here...

> http://jsbin.com/ititac/10/edit

as you can see the **horizontal images already centered..**

but the problem are the two vertical image are not centered...

also please take note they're just not a two images.

*It could be a hundreds of sample images...*

Thanks  hope you can help me with this...

Answer (score 0):

try this css: Hope it fixes your problem:

```
#product_thumbs .product_thumb {
float: left;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px dashed #B52020;
margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#product_thumbs .product_thumb img {
  width: 90px;
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  left: 30%;
  height: 80%;
  width: 90%;
  margin: -15% 0 0 -25%;
}
```

and here is the demo

```
http://jsbin.com/ititac/18/edit
```

hope below link will be useful:

```
http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/
```

Comment: oh it might good thanks for that..Ideally, we need the image in the same size as possible...the one you have provided above, are the images have stretched out..so it would be better if the image size will remain its size or if might re-size a bit only as possible.

Comment: i am not sure of how your are doing them. In general if all the images are populated from the server, then create a thumbnail for each image on the server. Popolate with these thumbnails. Hope that should ne easy way... Thank YOu

Comment: Thanks for the references sir DomincJune, I will try to get solution from this...i appreciate your help!